# Redirecting to "All Posts" after post publish or update

Tags: posts, wp-admin

How can I redirect to "All Posts" after publishing or updating a post (or CPT), instead of staying on the edit screen?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Note that WP 5.0 is iminent with a brand new editor, the solution may be obsolete or defunct in the near future if built using the classic editor

Comment: I think the default workflow has never been ideal. When editing many posts, after saving you have to click on posts, then eventually navigating to the posts page, then select your next post to edit etc. I felt there was a post/page overview or quick search missing in the edit screen, and I think that is what he is trying to "fix".

Comment: @Michael Yes indeed